# How can I tell IntelliJ IDEA that my app_es.properties is in Spanish?

Tags: internationalization, intellij-idea

I have resource bundles in English and Spanish, and IntelliJ IDEA complains with lots of "typo in word" for Spanish words in my `xxx_es.properties` files.

How can I "teach" IDEA Spanish so it can handle these `xxx_es.properties` files (or other languages)?

It should treat keys as English and values as Spanish, like in:

```
save=Guardar
```

Thank you = Gracias !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to specify that a file or directory is in a particular language. Nor is there a way to suppress the warnings for a file. You can however add a Spanish dictionary. IDEA would then "allow" either English or Spanish words in any file. Go to *File > Settings > [IDE Settings] > Spelling*.  Open the *Dictionaries* tab. You can then add a directory that contains multiple *.dic dictionary files, or add individual *.dic files. The *.dic file is just a line delimited list of words. I'm sure a little Goggling will turn up a Spanish *.dic file. Alternatively, the [Aspell](http://aspell.net) project has a large number of [dictionaries](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/0index.html) available. There is a [SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/questions/137957/how-to-convert-aspell-dictionary-to-simple-list-of-words) that has information on how you can convert an aspell dictionary to a plain text file. Just give it a *.dic extension.